Different expressions for $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ in spherical polar coordinates and for a 2-sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
In spherical polar coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$,
\begin{align}
x & = r \sin \theta \cos \phi,\tag1 \\
y & = r \sin \theta \sin \phi,\tag2 \\
z & = r \cos \theta,\tag3
\end{align}
the expression for the partial derivative with respect to $z$ and $y$ (similar thing for $x$) are:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \cos \theta \, \frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin \theta}{r} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \sin \theta \sin \phi \, \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{\cos \theta \sin \phi}{r} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\cos \phi}{r \sin \theta} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}.
\end{equation}
with r fixed at $r=1$,
we have,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} &= - \sin \theta\, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta},\tag4 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} &= \cos \theta \sin \phi \, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\cos \phi}{\sin \theta} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}. \tag5
\end{align}
Now when we consider the 2-sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, from this answer, we have,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} &= -\sin \theta \, \frac{\partial}{\partial z},\tag6 \\
\cos \phi \, \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} &= \sin \theta \, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}. \tag7
\end{align}
Question.1: Why do we have two different expressions in above two cases?
Question.2: Interestingly if we find the generator of rotation about the x-axis (any other generator of rotation, which are the Killing vector fields of the 2-sphere), $L^x=z \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, we get the correct answer in both cases, $L^x=\cot \theta \cos \phi \, \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} + \sin \phi \, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}.$ Why is this so? Is this just a coincidence or am I missing something?
PS: Is writing $(3)$ from $(7)$ correct when we have r=1 in case of the 2-sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, that is when we have a constraint equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ ?

I believe, the whole miscalculation stems from the fact that you treat the contravariant vectors ($\partial_{\alpha}$) as covectors. In fact, they are inversely related by the metric.

Can you please elaborate a bit? I am too confused at this point about the problem.

@EgorLarionov From the answer in the link, I am not sure about equation (6), as z is not independent of x and y when the constraint equation is at place. Also I am not familiar with musical isomorphism. For some background, I am a Physics student taking a general relativity course.

I just changed the answer in the link. Let me know what you think now. I believe you have indeed highlighted an embarrassing problem in the earlier version.

@KurtG. The derivation of the killing vector is no doubt correct in the updated answer. So the only question which remains now, was getting the correct answer for the fields even with the wrong partial derivatives just a coincidence? The concept which I need some more clarification on, is the distinction between co-ordinate basis and partial derivative operators. Would they transform in the same manner in case of embedded surfaces?

I needed to go on a hike this afternoon to think through where the problem was with the earlier version. I know there was one but cannot precisely point out more than that the field $\cos\phi,\partial_x+\sin\phi\partial_y$ can impossibly vanish (which was a disturbing consequence of the earlier approach). I guess when applying the chain rule one should not do so under constraints. Right at the start must have been the problem. Let me digest this for some time. I thank you for the critical reading.

@KurtG. Thanks to you as well for all the helpful interaction. I have thought of a possible explanation in terms of pushing forward of the vector field from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $S^2$. I am thinking of putting it as an answer here. It would be helpful if you go through the response as I am new to this subject.

@EgorLarionov Can you please take a look at the answer I have added?

@KurtG. What I can think of is that equation (4) is concerned with the partial derivative operator acting on any function $f$ and is not about the basis vectors.

Just deleted that comment as I am digesting @TedShifrin 's answer which I am very grateful for. The correct relationships between those partial derivatives are contained in there. (4) looks dubious and my (6) is wrong as I said.

I apologise, I could not visit the site for some time, but I think Ted’s answer has covered it all. That’s indeed what I meant when I said you used a mixup of contravariant vectors and transforms. If there’s any clarification you need from me that I might have missed, just let me know.

@EgorLarionov I would be grateful if you take a look at my answer as well and provide some feedback. I have deleted the previous comment. Thank you.

It is easier to work with the covectors and then go to the dual basis.
We have
\begin{align*}
dx &= \cos\theta\cos\phi\,d\theta - \sin\theta\sin\phi\,d\phi \\
dy &= \cos\theta\sin\phi\,d\theta + \sin\theta\cos\phi\,d\phi \\
dz &= -\sin\theta\,d\theta
\end{align*}
Of course, $x\,dx+y\,dy+z\,dz=0$ on $S^2$, and so locally we use $dy,dz$ as a local coframe. This gives
$$\begin{bmatrix} dy \\ dz \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta\sin\phi & \sin\theta\cos\phi \\ -\sin\theta & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} d\theta \\ d\phi \end{bmatrix}.$$
Then
$$\begin{bmatrix} d\theta \\ d\phi \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta\sin\phi & \sin\theta\cos\phi \\ -\sin\theta & 0 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} dy \\ dz \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\csc\theta \\ \csc\theta\sec\phi & \cot\theta\csc\theta\tan\phi\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} dy \\ dz \end{bmatrix}.$$
Since $\partial/\partial\theta,\partial/\partial\phi$ is the dual basis to $d\theta,d\phi$, etc., we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}\partial/\partial\theta \\ \partial/\partial\phi\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta\sin\phi & \sin\theta\cos\phi \\ -\sin\theta & 0 \end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix} \partial/\partial y\\\partial/\partial z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta\sin\phi & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta\cos\phi & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \partial/\partial y\\\partial/\partial z\end{bmatrix}.$$
(If two bases are related by the invertible matrix $A$, then the dual bases are related by $(A^{-1}){}^\top$, as you can easily check:
If $e_i=a^k_i e_k'$ and $e^i = b^i_\ell e'^\ell$, then
$$\delta_i^j = e^j(e_i) = b^j_\ell e'^\ell(a^k_i e_k') = b^j_\ell a^k_i \delta^\ell_k = b^j_ka^k_i.)$$
EDIT: It follows from what I have above that
$$\begin{bmatrix} \partial/\partial y \\ \partial/\partial z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \csc\theta\sec\phi \\ -\csc\theta & \cot\theta\csc\theta\tan\phi\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \partial/\partial\theta \\ \partial/\partial\phi\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus,
\begin{align*}
L^x &= z\frac{\partial}{\partial y} -y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
&=\cos\theta\csc\theta\sec\phi\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}-\sin\theta\sin\phi\left(-\csc\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} + \cot\theta\csc\theta\tan\phi\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\right) \\
&=\sin\phi\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} + \cot\theta(1-\sin^2\phi)\sec\phi\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi} = \sin\phi\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} + \cot\theta\cos\phi\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi},
\end{align*}
agreeing with your previous formula.

Thank you. Okay, So how do I interpret the equations (4) and (5) in question? Are those just concerned with the partial derivative operator? I would be grateful if you look at the issue with the Killing fields. Particularly in scenarios when we consider the surface being embedded in a higher dimensional space and use the symmetry properties to get the killing fields. I am not getting the correct expression for the killing fields when using the above expression for $\partial_z$ and $\partial_y$ in $L^x=z \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$.

Also can you give some feedback on my attempt below regarding the killing vector field?

I'll post an answer to the question from the comment section in here.

Okay, so what is wrong with equations $(4)$ and $(5)$? Are those concerned with the partial derivative operators rather than the dual basis?

Yes and no. You see, partial derivatives and differential forms do indeed form a dual basis, and from what I see you use the "typical" chain rule (that's for differential forms) for partial derivatives.
For clarity, supposing we use the same coordinate change, let's see how it affects the partial derivative operator explicitly. For any arbitrary function $f$ on the surface of the sphere:
$$
f(x, y, z) = f\left(x(\theta, \varphi), \, y(\theta, \varphi), \, z(\theta, \varphi)\right) 
$$
In these new coordinates let's see how the differential operators behave:
$$
\partial_\theta f = 
\partial_xf \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} +
\partial_yf \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} +
\partial_zf \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} 
$$
From the coordinate change we know the explicit derivatives of the old coordinates with respect to new ones:
$$
\partial_\theta f = \left[
\cos{\theta}\cos{\varphi} \, \partial_x +
\cos{\theta}\sin{\varphi} \, \partial_y -
\sin{\theta} \, \partial_z \right] f
$$
If you find all the partial derivatives and choose an appropriate local coframe, you'll see the answer will be the same as Ted's.

I have thought of a possible explanation of why we end up getting the correct answer for the killing vector fields, even if we are using eqautions (6) and (7).
If we consider the map $f: (x, y, z) \rightarrow (\theta, \phi)$ defined by:
\begin{align}
\theta &= \cos^{-1}(z), \\
\phi &= \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right).
\end{align}
The Jacobian matrix of this transformation is given by:
\begin{align}
J = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix} 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - z^2}} \\
-\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2} & \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
The push-forward of the vector field $(0, z, -y)$, which is $L^x$ under the map $f$ is:
\begin{align}
f_*(0, z, -y) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{y}{\sqrt{1 - z^2}} \\
\frac{xz}{x^2 + y^2}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Now if we put,
\begin{align}
x & = \sin \theta \cos \phi,\tag1 \\
y & = \sin \theta \sin \phi,\tag2 \\
z & = \cos \theta,\tag3
\end{align}
we get the killing vector field in the $\partial_{\theta}, \partial_{\phi}$ basis as, $(\sin\phi,\cot\theta\cos\phi)$.

Honestly, I couldn't understand why this is an explanation. From the way I see it, you made a coordinate change and found the coordinates of the field in the new basis. To be honest, I've never come across the Killing vector field. Unless someone provides a better insight on why this could be a coincidence or not, I'll take a look at the new notion tomorrow and see what I can advise.

It is better to avoid inverse trig functions (especially since these formulas are valid only on part of the appropriate domain) and do the inversion of the derivative matrices, as I have done in my answer.

@TedShifrin Okay, I get that. Thank you. Also, I would be grateful if you could address the issue of finding the killing fields using this method as my primary motivation was finding the killing fields in a similar manner for the $AdS_3$ space. Should I post a new question?

What's confusing here is that you have vector fields defined on all of $\Bbb R^3$, not just on the unit sphere. And yet you're interested in just the sphere. In general, you have vector fields defined on submanifolds that are not necessarily defined on the entire ambient space. I don't know how you are actually intending to work with your AdS situation. Once you have a specific question, yes, you should write up a clear exposition with your efforts.

So the strategy looks as the following: If we consider the embedding of the $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, it has $SO(3)$ symmetry. So now the I want to express the generators of SO(3) $L^{X^i X^j} =  X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial X^j} - X^j \frac{\partial}{\partial X^i}$ ln the $S^2$. What I was trying to do was naively express $\partial_z$ and $\partial_y$ in terms of $\partial_{\theta}$, $\partial_{\phi}$ and plug in the equation for the generator. Intended to solve for the AdS$_3$ situation by embedding it as a hyperboloid in a space with signature $(-,-,+,+)$ which would have SO$(2,2)$ symmetry.
